# AngularJs $http not working

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to use $http GET requests but it is not working and i don't know what is wrong with it and am not also getting any errors in the console ,this is the whole code that am using

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="twitchApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TwichTv</title><!-- End of Title -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container contentContainer">
       <div class="contentWrapper">
         <div class="innerContent">
              <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs statusBar" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" id="all" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">All</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" id="online"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Online</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" id="offline"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Offline</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div ng-controller="allUsersController" class="tab-content result">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="allTab">
                  <div class="well">
                    <div class="userLogo">
                      <img ng-src="{{ image }}">
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="username">{{ userName }}</h3>
                    <p><span class="info">{{ channelStatusInfo }}</span></p>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                      <span class="statusIcons"><i id="icon" class="fa fa-user green"></i></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-controller="onlineUsersController" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="onlineTab">
                  <div class="well"></div>
                </div>
                <div ng-controller="offlineUsersController" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="offlineTab">
                  <div class="well"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and javascript

```
var streamers = ["freecodecamp", "storbeck", "terakilobyte", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "thomasballinger", "noobs2ninjas", "beohoff", "brandonlehr", "MedryBW"];
var streamurl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";
var userurl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/";
var online = "green glyphicon glyphicon-user";
var offline = "glyphicon glyphicon-user";


var twitchApp = angular.module("twitchApp", []);

twitchApp.controller("allUsersController",[ '$scope', '$http', allUsersController]);

function allUsersController($scope, $http) {
    streamers.forEach(function(streamer){
        var userUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/" + streamer;
        var req = {
            method : 'GET',
            url: userUrl
        };

        $http(req).then(function(result) {
            var streamUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + streamer;
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url:  streamUrl
            }).then(function(data){
                $scope.userName = result.name;
                if(result.logo === null) {
                    $scope.image = "http://fit.ie/fitnew/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/no-profile-image.jpg";
                }
                // check if streamer is streaming
                if(data.stream === null) {
                    $('#icon').removeClass('green');
                } else {
                    var ii = data.stream;
                    for(var item in ii) {
                        $scope.channelStatusInfo = ii.channel.status;
                    }

                }
            });

        });// the main then callback


    });// the forEach loop
}
```

so can anyone help with why it is not working

Comment: The code must be in the question. It should also describe what you expect the code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: @JBNizet yes but it is with the html and css so it gonna be so big so i dicide to have link instead. there is not errors displaying

Comment: If it's a problem with $http, I don't see how html and css are relevant. If all you can say is: I have this big pile of code and it doesn't work, then you should first reduce the code to a minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet yes it the $http but when i get the data i am trying to display that data to the view and about the code it is not that much am gonna do it now

Comment: You failed to tell what you expected that code to do, and what it does instead. But one spottable error is that what is passed to then() is a HTTP response, which has a `status`, a `data`, a `headers` and a `config` fields, but no `stream` field. Use your browser dev tools debugger to inspect the objects.

Comment: @JBNizet i don't get that can you explain in detail

Comment: `then(function(data) { if(data.stream === null) { ... } })` should be `then(function(httpResponse) { var data = httpResponse.data; if(data.stream === null) { ... } })`. Not sure how I can be clearer than my previous explanation.

Comment: now i got little but let me try that code first

Comment: @JBNizet i work some place not the whole but what did you do how this code works